# Reaction of 1,4-Dichlorobenzene & Hydroxylamine

Tags: reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, halogens

I'm looking for reactions that would attack the chlorine in dichlorobenzenes. Wikipedia mentions a reaction with hydroxylamine, yet Googling, I haven't found exact said reaction. Can anyone provide it and why it would attack the chlorine?

Comment: [Don't capitalize element names unless it is at the beginning of the sentence.](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/58/17368)

Answer (score 3):

*Sukhov* et.al tried to aminate chlorobenzene and they found the products to be isomeric chloroanilines and chlorophenylenediamines but I am not if they went ahead and tried to aminate *di/tri*chlorobenzene but I am pretty sure it would lead to mixture of isomeric aniline/chloroaniline/mixed di/tri-chloro-di/tri-amino compounds or even di/triaminobenzene. The mixture will contain so many isomers and mixed substituted product that it will be hard to pinpoint where is the actual attacking point. The following is the abstract of their paper:

> The process of electrochemical amination of chlorobenzene using hydroxylamine and the Ti(IV)/Ti(III) mediator system is studied in aqueous solutions of 6–16 M sulfuric acid containing acetic acid or acetonitrile. The substitution products in these media are isomeric chloroanilines and chlorophenylenediamines, with the exception of 5-chloro-1,3-isomer, phenylenediamines, and aniline. The overall current efficiency of amino compounds corresponding under the experimental conditions to the efficiency by hydroxylamine can reach 71%. Para- and ortho-chloroanilines are obtained in 6 M sulfuric acid and 11.1 M acetic acid with the weight fraction and current efficiency of 97 and 51%, respectively.

**Ref**.: Lisitsyn, Y.A., Sukhov, A.V. Electrochemical Amination of Chlorobenzene in Aqueous-Organic Solutions of Sulfuric Acid. Russ J Electrochem 54, 886–892 (**2018**). DOI: [10.1134/S1023193518130268](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S1023193518130268)